# Prevent event firing for checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two event handlers for one single checkbox. I want to first handler to prevent the second one from firing. Here is an example:

```
$("#address_cb").change(function(event) {
    alert('foo');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$("#address_cb").change(function(event) {
    alert('should never display');
});

$("#address_cb").trigger("change");


https://jsfiddle.net/zxzzLkky/5/
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: a public variable can help this

Comment: try using "return false;" or use event.stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: @GüvenAltuntaş firstly: global gariables are bad idea. Secondly - it's jQuery, where `query` means `multiple variables`. I have a lot of checkboxes with 2 generic handlers for everyone. I can create an array with flags, of course, but it not seems to be a good thing.

Comment: event is not passed in callback function

Comment: @AlexanderKludt `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, worked, thank you for a comment.

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Even.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

```
$("#address_cb").change(function(event) {
   alert('foo');
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Works
   return false; //would call event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() but not stopImmediatePropagation()
});
```

as both of your events fire on the same event level. <s>As an alternative you might just return false for your callback as jQuery will care about the rest.</s>

See [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for differences on return false method

Comment: as I said it's only `stopImmediatePropagation()` which is working. `return false` and other just does nothing.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right - return false will only do stopPropagation and preventDefault. Will correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using event.stopImmediatePropagation() instead of event.stopPropagation();. Please test it propely. Hope this work. Reference 
https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

```
$("#address_cb").change(function(event) {
    alert('foo');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```